# jquery form plugin with file uploading

Tags: jquery

i need a jquery form plugin with uploading images option.
is there anything?

Comment: This is very hazy: What do you mean by "form plugin"? What exactly does an option to upload images entail - resizing? Cropping? I think I can guess what you mean but you should clarify anyway

Comment: ok,let me clarify my mean.i have a form and have some fields that allow user to upload some photos,one or more.i guess jquery have some nice solution for this mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need a jquery form plugin with uploading images option. is there anything?

The [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) supports file uploads, if that's what you mean.